"Failed to Start Gnome Display Manager" Ubuntu 22.04
I’m having troubles starting my Ubuntu session on my computer, which is set up in a dual boot with Windows. I keep getting an error message that says: Failed to start Gnome Display Manager.
After several troubleshooting attempts, I discovered that my hard drive is full, particularly the partition /dev/nvme0n1p6. I have tried several solutions to free up space, including:
Cleaning the package cache:
I used sudo apt clean to remove old cached files.
Deleting temporary files and system logs:
I attempted to delete files in /tmp and cleaned the logs with sudo journalctl --vacuum-time=3d.
I also used sudo apt autoremove which allowed me to remove unnecessary packages, but I still don't see a significant improvement in space.
When I wanted to update the packages, I saw that the /var/cache/apt/archives folder was full as well.
Despite all these attempts I still cannot get my Ubuntu session to start.

Open Gparted.  What does p6 have on it as a file system, and is this a Windows Partition?

Hi @eyoung100, unfortunately I can'tvsee with gparted cause I don't have any usb key, but /devnvme0n1p6 seems to be my hard disk. And it is not a Windows partition

I fixed it with Gparted by extending the storage capacity. I don't think there was another solution in my case because apparently my Ubuntu version needs a lot space.
